# Public Search - Endpoint Suddenly Removed

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have an app that was utilizing the public search endpoint from the Instagram API. Just today (4/4/2018) I started getting the errors "This endpoint has been retired". I can longer get any content.

My API call looked like this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search/?access_token=123456&q=instagram&count=1
```

This wasn't supposed to happen until Dec 11, 2018 according to their website: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/

Any way to get this information or do I need to overhaul the API.

Comment: You are not alone ... :(

Comment: Noticed the same this morning for endpoint `https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/[ID]/likes`

Comment: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/[ID]/comments` is still working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to them on the Instagram developer website. https://www.instagram.com/developer/

> To continuously improve Instagram users' privacy and security, we are accelerating the deprecation of Instagram API Platform, making the following changes effective immediately. We understand that this may affect your business or services, and we appreciate your support in keeping our platform secure.
>
> These capabilities will be disabled immediately (previously set for July 31, 2018 or December 11, 2018 deprecation). The following will be deprecated according to the timeline we shared previously.):
>
> Public Content - all remaining capabilities to read public media on a user's behalf on December 11, 2018
> Basic - to read a user’s own profile info and media in early 2020
> For your reference, information on the new Instagram Graph API.[image]

Comment: This is nonsense, I would love to see someone from IG Devs to reply,... Why would you deprecate a feature (public access) that's available on their own website?

Do they want developers to scrap the website instead of using a controlled API?

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was a workaround but it appears I'm just stuck. Thanks!